# chat message window in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to create a chat message window or panel / speech bubble which look like as follows using jquery mobile

I want a round rect window and a small call out which can be plugged either way of a chat message box

[image]

is there any plugins out there for the same ?

Comment: any use? http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/chat

Comment: You can make those shapes with CSS if you're feeling frisky. Take a look at this blog post: http://www.sadcow.co.uk/#11

Comment: @ghostCoder  , i saw that before but its not what i want

Comment: To clarify, are you looking for a plugin that will handle chat for you that looks the way you describe? Or a plugin to make things look like speech bubbles, and you'll write the chat yourself?

Comment: @Grim... i rectify the changes but it was chat message window only